# How to slice the string using logql?

Tags: grafana-loki, logql

I have values in my logs in grafana loki something like this

data  1234-02-01,12:30,1
data  1234-03-02,11:30,12

I am able to slice these values and separate date and time from this using trunc but I don't seem to do for the last value because it could be either single digit or double digit.

I used this:-

date= {{.data | trunc 10 }} time= {{.data | trunc -10 | trunc 8}} val= {{.data | trunc -1}}

this gives me

date  1234-03-02 , 1234-02-01

time  12:30 , 11:30

val   1 , 2

last val always give the last digit, so if I want to fetch 12 it will only give me 2 . What can I do to fetch the entire digit after time and comma. So I want 1 if its a single digit and 12 if its a double digit and 123 if its a three digit and so on. I hope this makes sense. Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

try to use [patter parser](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/08/09/new-in-loki-2.3-logql-pattern-parser-makes-it-easier-to-extract-data-from-unstructured-logs/)

for this line: `data 1234-02-01,12:30,1` , the query might look like:

```
{*some labels selector} | pattern "data <date>,<time>,<value>"
```